# Angular JS - How to make links clickable from WP rest api for Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, rest, ionic-framework

I have a Ionic and Angular JS app, I have a restful api coming from Wordpress, What I would like to know is, is it possible to have the links from the rest api clickable within the app?

Thanks

Comment: There should be no issues with that.

Comment: But in the app the link do not launch..

Comment: Are you making them into an `<a>` tag?

Comment: Yes but they do not launch in the app

Comment: If it's a link to different URL outside of application it may open in default browser I think, not in app. Ionic uses UI Router. Try with `ui-sref` may be if you can get the state (If it's in same app)

Comment: But the link is coming from a restful api

Comment: post some code please!

Comment: Do yourself a favor and start a new Ionic tabs project that will give you an example chat app and how they go about handling in app routing. There are a few things that you will need to research but it will help you understand these concepts in the future. Give it a try and if you are still stuck post some code so everyone can see how you have tried to do things.